# Spring Google OAuth Login asking for credentials on tomcat restart

Tags: spring, tomcat, oauth-2.0

I have been working on Integrating Google Login using OAuth in Spring. It is working fine but on every tomcat restart, it asks for credentials. What could be possible reasons?

EDIT : I am using [OAuthConfig](https://github.com/lorenzodee/spring-security-oauth2-google/blob/master/src/main/java/web/sample/OAuth2ClientSecurityConfig.java) and [GoogleTokenServices](https://github.com/lorenzodee/spring-security-oauth2-google/blob/master/src/main/java/oauth2/google/GoogleUserInfoTokenServices.java) from the same project. Running SmartTomcat in IntelliJ.

Comment: Provide more details about your setup.

Comment: @KamilW. Updated please see.

Comment: I guess SmartTomcat can wipe your cookies (which hold ouath session) on restart. Try to deploy your application on standalone tomcat, which by default keeps cookies for some period, and check if issue gone.

Comment: @KamilW. I tried with Tomcat also deployed war and restarted. It was asking for credentials again